# Capture Play button event in webview - Windows 8 apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a webview with an iframe embedded in it

[image]

and the code snippet

```
string iframeStr = string.Format(
                      @"<iframe width='{0}' height='{1}' src='{2}' frameborder='{3}'>
                      </iframe>",
                      560,
                      315,
                      "http://www.youtube.com/embed/0QXbHFmc09Y",
                      0));
watchTrailerView.NavigateToString(iframeStr);
```

Is it possible to know or capture the click event of the play button within the iframe if there is anything like that.